# Adam optimizer with distributed training

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, adam, parallel-computing

Does Adam optimizer applicable to either method of distributed training BSP, ASP, SSP or it can be used with synchronous mode only  ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[Adam](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980) alone in standard form is used for optimisation for a single dataset. Depending on your distributed algorithm, one can of course use Adam in local training part of algorithms, there is no restriction on that. However, there is a distributed version of Adam, so called [DADAM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09109). For [DS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.11848) type distributed setting, Adam can be used for local workers of course. (A)synchrony is about task scheduling rather than optimisation, so one can separate optimisation as an independent work load.